# Graph program name

Tags: software-recommendation, graph

Does anyone know the name of the program that gives graph output in this format? Notice how the numbers at the top are between lines instead of before or after.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of diagram. As a graphic designer I'm just thinking any vector application could have been used to make this. And the placement of the numbers would be a design decision. But there might be a graph program that outputs this design by default of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can 100% achieve an exact copy of that using a table in InDesign, however we can't possibly tell what was used to produce your original image.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to imitate this look is to use a spreadsheet:

[image]

This is Excel, but freeware such as OpenOffice do the same as well.

Black squares are cells with black fill color.

The placements of the numbers and their typing directions vary. Numbers 10 and 20 occupy actually 2 cells each. 1 and 0 are in adjacent cells, only justified differently.

As said, this imitates only the visual look. No idea which program, data and functions would produce the same automatically